# Rails form not working with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, turbolinks

This question seems to be the same as mine: [Rails turbolinks break submit remote form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281918/rails-turbolinks-break-submit-remote-form?rq=1)
 ( [This question is also similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231797/form-with-remote-true-not-working-with-turbolinks), [As is this github issue](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/298) )

However the answers posted there did not solve my issue...

#### The issue I am having:

On the users show page there is a simple form to submit new to-do items. The form is setup to use AJAX. The form submit works correctly on initial page load or page refresh. **However, it does not work at all** (clicking the submit button does nothing, not in rails or with AJAX) **after you navigate anywhere within the app.** Meaning, once you have navigated out of the show view and back without refreshing the page, clicking the submit button on the form does nothing.

The above quoted issues all seem to suggest that it is an issue with turbolinks, however the answers posted there either did not work, or I could not understand them well enough to fix my issue...

Any help would be *amazing!!!*

Here is code that may be helpful:

`_form.html.erb (rendered in the show view)`

```
<%= form_for [task], remote: true do |f| %>
    <tr class="new-task">
        <td class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Add new task..." %>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <%= f.date_field :expires_at, max: Time.now + 7.days, min: Time.now + 1.day %>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

`create method in TasksController`

```
def create
    expires_at_format unless params[:task][:expires_at].blank? # adds the current time to a user created date

    @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)

    if @task.save
        flash.now[:notice] = "\"#{@task.name}\" added to To-Do list!"
    else
        if @task.errors.any?
            flash.now[:alert] = "Task not saved. #{@task.errors.full_messages.join '. ' }."  
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Something went wrong! Your task was not saved... "
        end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
    end
end
```

`create.js.erb (AJAX to handle displaying new tasks)`

```
<% if @task.valid? %>
    $('.task').children('.expires_at').each(function(){ 
        if ($(this).text() <= "<%= @task.expires_at.to_s %>") {
            $(this).parent().before("<%= escape_javascript(render(@task)) %>");
            return false;
        } 
    }); 
    $('#task_name').val("");
    $('th#task-count').html("You have <%= pluralize(current_user.tasks.unexpired.count, "Task").split.insert(1, "active").join ' ' %>");
    $(".flash").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash.now[:notice] %></div>");
<% else %>
    $('#task_name').val("");
    $('.flash').html("<div class='alert alert-warning'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash.now[:alert] %></div>");
<% end %>
```

`from application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require toggleExpired
//= require_tree .
```

'from gemfile`

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on persist logging in your JS debugger/console (so you can see the console across page loads)? It seems to me like you hare having some sort of JS error that is breaking the execution stack. Specifically, I would look into [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) (It looks like you don't have it installed).

Also, are you 100% confident Turbolinks is causing the issue?  It is fairly easy to disable this specific gem to further isolate the issue.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time to answer :) 
I have turned on persist logging, and tried adding the jquery-turbolinks gem, to no avail.... Any other ideas? (and disabling turbolinks does solve the issue, but I do not want to remove turbolinks unless I have no other choice...)

Comment: Are you loading jquery.turbolinks between jquery and jquery_ujs?  If I remember correctly the ordering is important (as specified in the documentation)

Comment: Also have you implemented any of the events i.e. `turbolinks:load` to make sure Turbolinks is actually working properly?  You should be able to just dump some random text to the console using console.log, ref: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events

Comment: Did you check the ordering of the loading of jquery.turbolinks?  It has to be loaded between jquery and jquery_ujs, if I remember correctly.  The documentation specifies this. 
 https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks.  Also, have you tried upgrading all of your Gems (in a separate working copy) as a test?